# Can two Macs use Time Machine to the same non-Time Capsule NAS?

Tags: mac, nas, time-machine

I'm considering a [Synology DS210j NAS](http://www.synology.com/us/products/ds210j/index.php) which supposedly supports Time Machine out of the box.

Can two Macs both use Time Machine to the same NAS? I know you can do it with Time Capsule, but I'm not sure if there is anything proprietary that enables it.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to. The sparsebundle that is created for remote backups includes the MAC address of the machine being backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely - I've done it with a HD connected to my iMac which also backed up my Macbook.
As long as you format it in Mac format with disk utility before you start.
The iMac created regular files whereas the Macbook created a sparse bundle.